# Replace string in one file with contents of another file

Tags: bash

I am looking for a `BASH` program that I can run to replace a matching string in file2 with all of the contents from file1.

So file2 looks like this:

```
define([
 'require'
  ****
 ],
 function(require){
 });
```

file1 looks like:

```
, 'app/js/controllers/x'
, 'app/js/controllers/y'
, 'app/js/controllers/z'
```

is there a simple `BASH` script I can use to copy the 3 lines from file1 and replace the `****` string with the file1 contents and then write the result to file3.js?

Comment: I think ```sed``` might be your tool of choice here. It will only be necessary to figure out how to load a whole file and insert it somewhere. I'll have a look for this…

Comment: yeah, I saw something about sed...another thing, is you don't really need bash, I guess, you just need to read the file, replace the string, write the file, that can be done with pretty much any programming language

Answer (score 6):

#### Using sed

```
$ sed $'/[*][*][*][*]/{r file1\nd}' file2
define([
 'require'
, 'app/js/controllers/x'
, 'app/js/controllers/y'
, 'app/js/controllers/z'
 ],
 function(require){
 });
```

This looks for the line containing `****`.  When found, it reads `file` and then deletes the line containing `****`.

#### Using awk:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{s=s"\n"$0;next;} /[*][*][*][*]/{$0=substr(s,2);} 1' file1 file2
define([
 'require'
, 'app/js/controllers/x'
, 'app/js/controllers/y'
, 'app/js/controllers/z'
 ],
 function(require){
 });
```

The first file is read into variable `s`.  When we see `****` in the second file, we replace it with `s` from the first file.

Answer (score 1):

You can read in the file line by line, and if you find the 4 stars in a row, instead of just printing the line, `cat` out `file1`. I use `tee` to print to `newfile.txt` and the terminal.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE1="file1.txt"
FILE2="file2.txt"

# read line by line
while IFS=''  read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
   # if we don't find 4 * in a row just print the line
   if [ $line != *"****"* ]; then 
        echo "$line"
   else
        cat $FILE1 # we found 4 stars, print the data from FILE1
   fi

done < "$FILE2" | tee newfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple sed command:

```
sed -i '/\*\*\*\*/ { r file1\nd }' file2
```

You are telling sed two things:

- Find string **** , read the file1 and append it.
- Delete string ****.

You need the curly braces to concatenate the orders.

Append the content of a file when sed match your string/regex:

```
sed '/yourString/r fileToAppend' inputFile.
```

Delete a string:

```
sed '/yourStringToDelete/d' inputFile
```

Comment: I did not write the semicolon. But I did not write it rightly originally. It is necessary the "new line" symbol that you put in your answer. I changed my answer to work. Thanks.